# Updating a table based on another table in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to find a solution to managing a table in Rails that is exclusively based on another table. Lets say I have a table called 'Transactions'. Each row contains the details of a certain transaction - user_id, amount, created_date. Now I would like to make another table, lets call it 'Rankings'. Rankings is an aggregate of the transactions table, so it contains a user_id and amount_total: the sum of all the transactions a user has made. I would like to update this table automatically when a new transaction is made. If the user has never made a transaction before, a new entry in Rankings is created, otherwise the amount associated with the user_id is += the new transaction amount.

I have an idea on how this might be done in plain SQL by creating a Rule to update based on a new transaction, but I am unsure how to implement this in my Rails api with ActiveRecord methods. Would all the logic be in my TransactionController since the update will happen based on a new transaction? Or would it better to call a method in a RankingsContoller?

Any ideas on making this both readable and relatively quick would be appreciated. Let me know if I need to further explain.

Comment: What you're asking for is a bad idea. It flies in the face of best practices of database design. Either create a view as Grzegorz has suggested, or simply calculate the ranking on-the-fly when you need it with an sql query that groups and aggregates, similar to grzegorz view. On-the-fly calculation would be the typical "Rails way" to produce the ranking values you need. Please don't create another table.

Comment: @LesNightingill Well my idea wasn't set in stone. I am new to this concept, thats why I was asking on SO what the best practices are. I am also inclined to go with what Grzegorz has suggested, but some research and follow up questions are needed on my part to understand it better.

Comment: OK, suppose (for the moment) you had a second table as you requested. How will you use it? What query(ies) will you apply to this second table to get the info you need?

Comment: I was thinking of putting method calls for updating and creating a record in the Rankings table in the TransactionsController. I could also have a RankingsController and a method for showing the current rankings. The second table was just how I had initially thought of it but like I said, I am open to suggestions that are the best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a query that gives you the sum. It's similar to Grzegorz' solution but without a view defined.This will give you a collection of User objects with a transaction_total attribute, containing the sum of the transactions for each user.

```rb
users = User.joins(:transactions).
             select("users.*, sum(transactions.amount) as transaction_total").
             group("user_id")

user.first.transaction_total #=> (e.g.) 2389.67
```

You don't need a separate table.

You can perform other calculations at the same time, based on the user_id grouping, for instance:

```rb
# write it like this for readability
select =<<-SEL.squish
  users.*,
  sum(transactions.amount) as transaction_total,
  min(transactions.amount) as transaction_min,
  max(transactions.amount) as transaction_max,
  avg(transactions.amount) as transaction_avg,
  count(transactions.id) as trans_count
SEL

users = User.joins(:transactions).
             select(select).
             group("user_id")

user.first.transaction_total #=> (e.g.) 2389.67
user.first.transaction_min   #=> (e.g.) 44.55
user.first.transaction_max   #=> (e.g.) 750.35
user.first.transaction_avg   #=> (e.g.) 88.33
user.first.trans_count       #=> (e.g.) 42
```

Note that I didn't call the count alias transaction_count. This particular method would be overridden by an ActiveRecord method, and would trigger a second query! This by virtue of the User has_many transactions relationship.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was actually also planning on calculating the max transaction, so the updated response is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Could you just go with creating a view (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-createview.html or https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_view.asp)?

```
CREATE VIEW rankings AS 
  SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) 
  FROM transactions 
  GROUP BY user_id
```

Now you can create a model Ranking that should work with a view just fine (you'd just not be able to persist any objects of Ranking)

A view is basically a query's name. Consider using materialized view https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rules-materializedviews.html if that suits your need better (not sure if MySQL has those yet...)

Comment: Do you mean a model as in a Rails model? how would the View fit in with the TransactionsController, as I only want to update the Ranking if a request to the Transactions is made?

Comment: ok, create a view as in database view, not MVC View. The idea behind the database view is that they are automatically up to date with the source table. To understand it better run `create view` query (the one from my answer above), and then `select * from rankings`, add a record to `transactions` table, run the `select * from rankings` and see that it's up to date.

Comment: If you can go with DB views, you don't need to worry about updating them on your application level.

Comment: Ah, Im starting to see what you mean. And by application level, you mean no computations to sum amounts in the rails controller itself?

Comment: yes, the `SUM(amount) ` in the SQL query will take care of that. (By Application level I mean Rails code)